# javascript letter character finder infinite loop glitch

Tags: javascript

My task was to create a while loop that counts the number of **letter** characters in a sentence written by the User. This function would only count the number of letter characters, no special characters. My issue it that when I add special characters (including numbers), in a some random given order (it works sometimes), it crashes my browser (it will crash yours too, be careful!). I don't know what is causing this.

```js
var chocolate = false;
var count = 0;
var characters = 0;
function letterCounter(){
  var sentence = document.getElementById('sentence').value;
  while(!chocolate){
    if (count==sentence.length) {
      var chocolate = true;
    }
    else if(sentence[count]=="a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"){
      count++;
      characters++;
    }
    else {
      count++;
    }
    document.getElementById('replaceTwo').innerHTML = characters;
}
}
```

```html
Function 2: letter count finder<br>
      <textarea id="sentence"></textarea><br>
      <button onclick="letterCounter()">Find letters</button>
      <div id="replaceTwo"></div>
```

Comment: One instance that always crashes the browser is when the __first__ character is a special character. Also, stackoverflows run example doesn't crash, so feel free to try it out.

Comment: Take the `document.getElementById('replaceTwo').innerHTML = characters;` statement out of the while loop. That may cause too many DOM updates in case of large sentences. 
Also, it would have been helpful if you'd included a sample sentence test case that crashes the browser in your code.

Comment: @SAIPALADUGU The snippet does actually make my Firefox crash when I use special characters :) (it makes the tab hang, for at least 30 sec, I was able to close the tab, but after 15 sec the whole browser crashed, with the bug report window from mozilla)

Comment: @Pac0 right. I found the issue. It won't crash in the first run because count is still 0, but after that. Posted a solution.

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh yes indeed I did a first run with correct characters. Good catch !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the variables `characters`, `chocolate` and `count` have been declared outside of the function and the function operates on them.
So, the function goes into an infinite loop **after** the first call if there are leading special characters in the input.

```js
function letterCounter(){
    var sentence = document.getElementById('sentence').value;
    var chocolate = false;
    var count = 0;
    var characters = 0;
    while(!chocolate){
        if (count==sentence.length) {
         chocolate = true;
        }
        else if(["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"].indexOf(sentence[count])!==-1){
         count++;
            characters++;
        } else {
         count++;
        }
 
    }
    console.log(characters)
}
```

```html
Function 2: letter count finder<br>
      <textarea id="sentence"></textarea><br>
      <button onclick="letterCounter()">Find letters</button>
      <div id="replaceTwo"></div>
```

This won't crash and incorporates @manuel-otto's fix.

Comment: I edited your snippet so it is actually runnable, with same HTML as in question, event though it makes the code a bit more "dirty", it was a quick fix.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
sentence[count]=="a","b","c",...
```

will not work as expected.

You will have to put those letters into an array check if that array contains the current letter:

```
["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"].indexOf(sentence[count])!==-1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are declaring a new variable `chocolate` inside your `if`:

```
if (count==sentence.length) {
  var chocolate = true;
}
```

Here is a working solution that won't crash your browser :)

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var sentence = document.getElementById('sentence');
var count = 0;
var re = /[a-z]/i;

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  count = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < sentence.value.length; i++) {
    if (re.test(sentence.value[i])) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('replaceTwo').innerHTML = count;
});
```

```html
<p>Function 2: letter count finder</p>
<textarea id="sentence"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="btn">Find letters</button>
<div id="replaceTwo"></div>
```